# Differential equation, Stability , Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given a system of differential equations 
\begin{eqnarray}
x'&=&2y(z-1)\\
y'&=&-x(z-1) \quad (1)\\
z'&=&xy
\end{eqnarray}
Note that $u_0$=(0,0,0) is an equilibrium point of the system. Let $V(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2$ is a Lyapunov function for (0,0,0). Since $V(u_0)=0$, $V(u)> 0$ for $u\neq u_0$ and $\frac{d}{dt} V(x,y,z)=0$ for $u\neq u_0$ then  $u_0$=(0,0,0) is stable by Lyapunov theorem.

But I don't understand that $u_0$=(0,0,0) is stable, infact it might be unstable. 
Here is my argument:
Let $r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ be the flow  of (1). Since $\frac{d}{dt} V(x,y,z)=0$ then $r'(t)\cdot \nabla V=0$. Hence, $r(t)$ always be in a surface $V(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2=C$ (A cylinder). If we make the radius of cylinder smaller then $x$ and $y$ component of $r(t)$ tend to 0 but $z$ component of $r(t)$ can be infinite since the height of cylinder is infinite. So, $r(t)$ can be far away from (0,0,0) and $u_0$=(0,0,0) is unstable.

Where is the error of my argument? Can we guarantee that $z$ component of $r(t)$ can't go to infinity? Can we esplain that $u_0$=(0,0,0) is stable without Lyapunov?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by $(0,0,0)$ being stable? If you want a "strong" kind of stability you need $dV/dt < 0$ along trajectories.

Comment: In Lyapunov theorem, if $dV/dt<0$ then the equilibrium is asymptotically stable and $dV/dt\leq 0$ then the equilibrium is stable (An equilibrium point $x_0$ is stable iff for every neighboorhood $U$ of $x_0$ there is a neighboorhood $U_1$ of $x_0$ in $U$ such that every solution $r(t)$ with $r(0)$ in $U_1$ is defined and in $U$ for all $t>0$)

Comment: The Lyapunov theorem as I know it requires the Lyapunov function to have a *strict* local minimum at the equilibrium point. Yours doesn't, hence the theorem is not applicable. And your reasoning showing that is certainly spot on.

Comment: I just took the definition from Hirsch and Smale's  Book. And it say like that. $dV/dt<0$ for asymptotically stable and $dV/dt\leq 0$ for  stable one. You can check the book now.

Comment: I'll check the book when I get to the office, in a half hour or so.

Comment: Well, an hour then … it is as I thought. Hirsch & Smale, Ch 9 §3, Theorem 1 (Liapunov's stability theorem, on p 193): Condition (a) is “$V(\bar x)=0$ and $V(x)>0$ if $x\ne\bar x$”. Your function $V$ does not satisfy the second part of this requirement.

Comment: Harald: I think $V$ does satisfy the requirement. The V here is $x^2+2y^2$ and at $\bar x=(0,0,0)$ we do have both parts of condition (a).

Comment: @coffeemath: No, for $V(0,0,z)=0$ for any $z$.

Comment: Harald: You're right. So the vector field of the question doesn't satisfy the Lyapunov condition! That leaves me wondering what it "looks like", e.g. is it "stable" near (0,0,0) or not?

Comment: @coffeemath: It is obviously stable, if my answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $(0,0,0)$ is Lyapunov stable.
The general idea has been suggested in other solutions, here are the truly gory details.

Let $p(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$.

We need to establish that a unique solution exists for all time. Let $r>0$ and let $K_r = \overline{B}(0,r)$. Since the system is smooth, it is Lipschitz on any bounded set. 
Let $p(t_0) \in  B(0,\frac{1}{2}r)$ be an initial condition at time $t_0$. By the existence and uniqueness theorem, a solution exists in $K_r$ for some small time interval $[t_0,t_1]$. As above, we notice that $x(t)^2+2 y(t)^2=x_0^2+ y_0^2$, and hence $(x(t),y(t))$ remains bounded. Since $\dot{z} = x y$, we have $|z(t)-z(t_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2}(x_0^2+ y_0^2)(t-t_0)$. Consequently, we see that for any given $t_1$ we can choose $r$ large enough so that $p(t) \in K_r$ for all $t\in [t_0,t_1]$. It follows that the solution exists and is unique for all $t \geq 0$.

Now we will establish that $t \mapsto p(t)$ is periodic. We know that $(x(t),y(t))$ lies on the ellipse $x^2+2y^2 = V_0$, where $V_0 = x_0^2+2 y_0^2$. First we will show that $(x(t),y(t))$ traverses the entire ellipse without $z(t)$ growing 'too much'. Then we will show that $z(t)$ is periodic as well.

We know that $|z(t)| \leq  |z(t_0)|+\frac{1}{2}V_0 (t-t_0)$. Hence if $|z(t_0)| < \frac{1}{4}$ and $(t-t_0) < \frac{1}{2 V_0}$, then $|z(t)| < \frac{1}{2}$. In particular, for any $T>0$, if $V_0$ and $|z(t_0)|$ are 'small enough', then $|z(t)| < \frac{1}{2}$ for any $t \in [t_0,t_0+T]$.

Since $(x(t),y(t))$ lie on the ellipse, we can write $x(t) = \sqrt{V_0} \cos \theta(t)$, $y(t) = \sqrt{\frac{v_0}{2}} \sin \theta(t)$ for some $C^1$ function $\theta$. Differentiating gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}(t) &=& -\sqrt{V_0}\sin \theta(t) \dot{\theta}(t) &=& -2 \sqrt{\frac{v_0}{2}} \sin \theta(t) (1-z) \\
\dot{y}(t) &=& \sqrt{\frac{v_0}{2}} \cos \theta(t) \dot{\theta}(t)  &=& \sqrt{V_0} \cos \theta(t) (1-z)
\end{eqnarray}
from which it follows that $\dot{\theta}(t) = \sqrt{2} (1-z)$. Now choose $T = 4 \sqrt{2} \pi$, which gives a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0,0)$ such that if $p(t_0) \in U$, then $|z(t)| < \frac{1}{2}$ for any $t \in [t_0, t_0+T]$. Then we have $\dot{\theta}(t) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and hence $\theta(t_0+T)-\theta(t_0) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} T = 4\pi$  (I choose $4 \pi$ so I can find a point where the positive $x$-axis is crossed and still have $2 \pi$ 'left to go'). Hence $(x(t),y(t))$ traverses the entire ellipse in some $[t_0,t_0+\delta] \subset [t_0, t_0+T]$. (It does not yet follow that $(x(t),y(t))$ is periodic.)

Let $\tau_0 \geq t_0$ be the first time at which $(x(t),y(t))$ crosses the positive $x$-axis, let $\tau_1 > \tau_0$ be the first time at which $(x(t),y(t))$ crosses the positive $y$-axis, and let $\Delta = \tau_1 -\tau_0$. For $t \in [\tau_0+\Delta, \tau_0+2\Delta]$, define $\tilde{x}(t) = -x(2\tau_0+2 \Delta-t)$, $\tilde{y}(t) = y(2\tau_0+2 \Delta-t)$ and $\tilde{z}(t) = z(2\tau_0+2 \Delta-t)$. It is straightforward to verify that $\tilde{p} = (\tilde{x},\tilde{y},\tilde{z})$ satisfies the differential equation with initial condition $\tilde{p}(\tau_0+\Delta)=p(\tau_0+\Delta)$.
By uniqueness, we have $p(t) = \tilde{p}(t) $ for $t \in [\tau_0+\Delta, \tau_0+2\Delta]$, and hence $(x(\tau_0+2\Delta), y(\tau_0+2\Delta),z(\tau_0+2\Delta))=(-x(\tau_0), y(\tau_0),z(\tau_0))$ (note that $y(\tau_0) = 0$ by choice of $\tau_0$).

Now we repeat the process for the remaining semi-ellipse. For $t \in [\tau_0+2\Delta, \tau_0+4\Delta]$, define $\tilde{x}(t) = x(2\tau_0+4 \Delta-t)$, $\tilde{y}(t) = -y(2\tau_0+4 \Delta-t)$ and $\tilde{z}(t) = z(2\tau_0+4 \Delta-t)$. Repeating the above procedure, we obtain $p(t) = \tilde{p}(t) $ for $t \in [\tau_0+2\Delta, \tau_0+4\Delta]$, and hence $(x(\tau_0+4\Delta), y(\tau_0+4\Delta),z(\tau_0+4\Delta))=(x(\tau_0), -y(\tau_0),z(\tau_0)) = p(t_0)$ (note that $y(\tau_0) = 0$ by choice of $\tau_0$).

It follows by uniqueness that $p(t+4 \Delta) = p(t)$ for all $t\geq t_0$. Furthermore, $|z(t)| \leq |z(t_0)| +\frac{1}{2}V_0 4 \Delta$ for all $t\geq t_0$.
Hence for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0,0)$ such that if $p(t_0) \in U$, then $\|p(t)\| <\epsilon$ for all $t \geq t_0$.

Answer (score 2):

The solution stays bounded, and $z$ undergoes periodic motion. The reason for this is symmetry: If you replace $x$ by $-x$ and $t$ by $-t$, the system is unchanged. Therefore, while $(x,y)$ travels once around its ellipse $x^2+2y^2=\text{constant}$ from $x=0$, $y>0$ back to the same point, $z$ must have returned to its original value.

I know that $x$, $y$ traverses the entire ellipse because the first two equations are just a variation of $x'=2y$, $y'=-x$, which has that property. More precisely, introduce some new time variable $\tau$. Write $x_\tau$ etc for the derivative wrt $\tau$ and $x_t$ etc for the derivative wrt $t$, then $x_\tau=x_t\tau_t$, so if $\tau$ is defined by $\tau_t=z-1$, then the first two equations become $x_\tau=2y$, $y_\tau=-x$. This works fine so long as $z<1$. But we are interested in stability at the origin, and if we start close to the origin then $z$ has no chance to grow as big as $1$ in the time it takes to traverse the ellipse.

Comment: How about the possiblity if the solution only trace the first octan? In this octan, z'=xy>0 so z always increasing. What make you sure that the solution trace along all quadrant of domain

Comment: I answered your question in the new second paragraph of my answer. There are still details to be filled in of course, but I have no time to do so in the near future. Maybe someone else will do it and claim your bounty.

Comment: How about this argument: We can reparameterize $S=\{(\sqrt{C}\cos u,\frac{\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{2}}\sin u, v): u,v\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Let $r(t)= (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ and  $r(0)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then $x(t)=\sqrt{C}\cos (t-t_0)$ and $y(t)=\frac{\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{2}}\sin (t-t_0)$ with $t_0$ satisfying $x_0=\sqrt{C}\cos t_0$ and $y_0=-\frac{\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t_0$. Since $z'=xy$ then $z'(t)=\frac{C}{2\sqrt{2}}\sin(2t-t_0)$, hence $z(t)=-\frac{C}{4\sqrt{2}}\cos(2t-t_0)$. Since $r(2\pi)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)=r(0)$ then $r(t)$ is periodic.

Comment: You should make this comment into an answer, in my opinion. Suggestion: say instead that $R^3$ may be given the coordinates of [insert here what you have in S = ...]. Then show that the solution to the z(t) from z'(t)=x*y is as you have in your comment a periodic function. Of course you are the one who asked the question, but on this site it is considered acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you can assert that $(x,y)$ traverse the entire ellipsoid. I realize the linearized system does, but without other conditions it does not follow that the actual trajectory will do so too.

Comment: @copper.hat: Surely, you must agree that the solution of $x_\tau=2y$, $y_\tau=-x$ traverses the entire ellipse? (Not ellipsoid – I don't know what possessed me to write that.) Hence so do $x$, $y$ when seen as functions of $t$, provided $\tau$ is allowed to change sufficiently. And from the definition $\tau_t=z-1$, we see that this is guaranteed so long as $z$ remains small (or better, stays away from $1$). If you start close to the origin, $xy$ remains small for all $t$, since $x^2+2y^2$ is constant. So $z'$ changes slowly, and $z$ takes as long as you may wish to reach $1$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I agree that it is obvious that the linear system traverses the ellipse. However, it is not immediate that the original system must follow suit. It does, but it took me some time to establish the fact formally. Hopefully there is a more succinct solution than the one I offered.

Answer (score 1):

At a specific height $z$ the equations $x'=2y(z-1)$ and $y'=-x(z-1)$ (looking at only the $x,y$ coordinates) make the trajectory go around an ellipse $x^2+2y^2=C$. (By this I mean ignoring where the $z$ coordinates are, i.e. looking at the projection of the trajectory onto the $xy$ plane.)

As the curve goes around the ellipse, the signs on $x,y$ go through the usual things in the four quadrants, so that $xy$ is first positive, then $0$, then negative, then $0$ and so on. So maybe this accounts for $z$ not going "off to infinity" by means of $z'=xy$, since because of the alternating signs on $xy$ the $z$ coordinate will oscillate rather than escape to infinity. Of course a better check would be to actually find the trajectories in closed form, but I don't see that easily. Consider this answer as only a possible explanation of why the trajectory might not escape to infinity in the $z$ direction.

Comment: How about the possiblity if the solution only trace the first octan? In this octan, z'=xy>0 so z always increasing. What make you sure that the solution trace along all quadrant of domain